# Method to "conda install" libraries and dependencies offline

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I am trying to install the geopandas library on a computer that is offline. The listed dependencies are: numpy, pandas, shapely, fiona, and pyproj. Each of these libraries have their own dependencies. My question is: Is there a simply way to get a full download of all libraries and their dependencies so that when I "conda install" geopandas from the folder of downloaded files, everything is built as required?

What I've tried is to create a new virtual environment and conda install the required files and then search on conda-forge (or elsewhere, if necessary) for the correct library version. This is pretty laborious and I'd like to find a more efficient method of doing this.

Comment: create a new enviroment on a machine with internet, conda install everything and replace enviroment of offline machine with the exported enviroment of the online conda enviroment?

Comment: Build a full version of the environment on a computer with identical OS, but online. Then use a tool like [conda-pack](https://conda.github.io/conda-pack/) or [conda-constructor](https://github.com/conda/constructor) to generate an offline transferable version of the environment.